# Do you need to check for null list or is it redundant?

Tags: java, list

I have the following code:

```
private void checkingFunction(Object1 myOb1, Object2 object2) {
        List<Person> person = getPersons();
        if (person != null && !person.isEmpty() && object2 != null) {
            object2.setValues(person.get(0).getTheValue() != null && !person.get(0).getTheValue().isEmpty());
        }
}
```

I was wondering if the if check is not needed and I can simplify the above code as follows:

```
private void checkingFunction(Object1 myOb1, Object2 object2) {
        List<Person> person = getPersons();
        
        object2.setValues(person.get(0).getTheValue() != null && !person.get(0).getTheValue().isEmpty());     
}
```

Is it correct to make such a change or is it better to use the control if?

Comment: If `getPersons` can return null your second example *will* throw an NPE, sooner or later. Probably when it's least desirable (i.e., never in a test environment, only in production).

Comment: And if it returns an empty list your second example will throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: Finally, if `object2` is `null` you'll also get a NPE at `object2.setValues(...)`.

Comment: null and empty objects are different and those checks have no overlap!

Comment: Those checks are important because each check is for a unique exception. But if you can't know if something is going to work or not until you actually do it, you can use try-catch. Note the try catch is relatively slower than if-else conditions use it with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 0):

The important **'RULE'** of writing program for product is that ***DO NOT believe any input data***.

If you believe that the return value of `getPersons();` will never be `null` , like your own, I don't care. Or you should validate the values.

I append small code to check it.

```java
private void checkingFunction(Object1 myOb1, Object2 object2) {
        List<Person> person = getPersons();
        
        boolean bResult = false;
        try {
            bResult = person.get(0).getTheValue() != null && !person.get(0).getTheValue().isEmpty();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // bResult = false;
        }

        object2.setValues(bResult);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My convention is that "List" items won't be null, ever. However for that, you need to code your methods that way. This for me includes things like JSON parsing too. If there are "no elements" I usually return an empty list just for convenience, therefore in large code bases I can avoid these kind of null checks. You need to decide (in this case in your "getPersons()" method) what you return and when.